# Retrieving JSON Title, URL from Pygooglenews feedParser

Tags: python, feedparser, google-news, pygooglenews

I'm trying to retrieve values from pyGoogleNews (https://github.com/kotartemiy/pygooglenews)
that is using feedParser to output the values.

[image: Lib Info]

Code Snippet as follows:

```
from pygooglenews import GoogleNews

gn = GoogleNews(lang = 'en', country = 'SG')
cars = gn.topic_headlines('CAAqJAgKIh5DQkFTRUFvSEwyMHZNR3MwYWhJRlpXNHRSMElvQUFQAQ')
print(cars)
```

which returns the following: (does not seem like a valid JSON file)

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to loop the "entries" list, to get the relevant title and link.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as follows:

```
for item in cars['entries']:
    print(item['title'])
    print(item['link'])
```